# Pipe filter is not expanding on a vanilla install of Sublime Text 3 with Emmet

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

Updating my Sublime Text 3, Emmet's comment filter (`|c`) is no longer expanding in HTML files.

Typing `.div_class` and hitting `tab` will expand to:

```
<div class="div_class"></div>
```

But typing `.div_class|c` and hitting `tab` will result in:

```
.div_class|<!--  -->
```

This has meant that I've been using VS Code for templating recently, but as VS Code doesn't have the option of full or partial word selection if the word uses underscores as separators, I'd rather stick with Sublime Text.

Comment: What is your desired output? `<div class="div_class"></div><!--  -->`? `<!-- <div class="div_class"></div> -->`? Something else?

Comment: That's right, so together with my `filter.commentAfter` settings, previously Emmet would output `<div class="div_class"></div><!-- .div_class -->`.

In case it helps anyone, those settings are:
`"filter.commentAfter"  : "<!-- <%= attr('class', '.') %> <%= attr('id', '#') %> -->"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe filters are no longer supported in new Emmet version. Instead, you should features like tag commenting in preferences. In Sublime Text, go to `Preferences > Packages Settings > Emmet > Settings` and set `"comment": true`.

Alternatively, you can enable "tag_preview" instead to display tag info when caret is inside closing tag: https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-text-plugin#tag-preview

Comment: That's great, thank you. It *doesn't* go inside the `preferences` JSON block, for anyone trying this. I definitely prefer having the closing comments, to make inspecting easier in the browser as well. Interestingly, this new (undocumented as far as I can see) way of Emmet doing closing comments isn't picking up the preferences `filter.commentAfter` any more, presumably because it isn't using a filter. I could raise another question here, but do you have any idea as to why this might be please?

Comment: You can just read comments in original Emmet preferences file, it’s called `comment_template` now.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the quick reply. For anyone coming to this in the future, here's what to put in the Emmet preferences file to get closing comments on the same line as the closing tag of your HTML element, with class first and then ID:
```
"comment": true,
"comment_template": "<!-- [.CLASS][#ID] -->",
```